# C array index in parentheses

Tags: c++, c

I happened to see `quantSpec[(1024)]` in FDKAAC audio codec. It's written in C, C++.

What does the parenthesis mean? Is it not as same as `quantSpec[1024]`?

Comment: It's just some redundant syntax that detracts from readablility. Do not copy.

Answer (score 3):

It means nothing, they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use of parentheses is necessary when you want to change the order of precedence of operations when evaluating an expression. Sometimes, especially in long expression in the conditionals of `if` and `while` statements, presence of parenthesis make the code easier to read.

```
3 + 5*10 == 2 + 50
```

You can change the order of operations by using parenthesis:

```
(3 + 5)*10 == 8*10
```

In the example that you have presented, removing the parenthesis will not change anything.

Comment: It's the *only* way to change the precedence, but adding them where unnecessary, as here, doesn't make anything easier to read. It just provokes questions like this one.

Comment: @EJP, I have found long statements in the conditionals of `if` and `while` statements that are easier to read when there are paranthesis.